# Error when trying to publish on QGIS Cloud

Tags: qgis-cloud

I get this error when trying to publish on QGIS Cloud:

```
Name contains invalid characters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rubenkalmbach/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 657, in request
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable Entity
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rubenkalmbach/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudplugindialog.py", line 659, in publish_map
    map = self.api.create_map( self.map(), fname, config)['map']
  File "/Users/rubenkalmbach/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 304, in create_map
    content = request.post(resource, data)
  File "/Users/rubenkalmbach/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 569, in post
    return self.request(resource, method='POST', data=data)
  File "/Users/rubenkalmbach/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 683, in request
    raise BadRequestError(msg)
qgiscloud.qgiscloudapi.qgiscloudapi.BadRequestError: Name contains invalid characters
```

Comment: "Name contains invalid characters" - so what name are you attempting to use?

Answer (score -1):

Try to save your project in qgs format and not in qgz which is a compressed format. It worked for me. Guess it is the extension or the fact that the project name contains two dots.